# Can't stop function from executing by using clearInterval()

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval, clearinterval, cleartimeout

I am creating a small game in JavaScript and I have an obstacle that is supposed to keep spawning every 3100 ms and when the "player" touches the obstacle, the obstacle should stop moving or re-spawning. But the code i have written is such that during the first spawn of the obstacle, the code works fine and the obstacle stops moving or re-spawning but from the second time it spawns, the code doesn't work properly.

Here's my code:

```
//Spawning Obstacle 

counter = 0;

function createObstacle() {
    counter++;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 520, 320);
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, 520, 320);
    ctx.drawImage(bomb, obX, obY, 20, 20);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
    obY += 10;
    if (counter == 31) {
        clearInterval(moveObstacle);
        console.log(counter);
        counter = 0;
        console.log(counter);
        obX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) * 50;
        obY = 0;
        score++;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 520, 320);
        ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, 520, 320);
        ctx.drawImage(bomb, obX, obY, 20, 20);
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
    }
}

function obstacle() { moveObstacle = setInterval(createObstacle, 100); }
obstacle();
var recreateObs = setInterval(obstacle, 3100);

//Game Over

function gameOver() {
    if ((x == obX && y - 20 == obY) || (x == obX && y + 10 == obY) || (x + 10 == obX && y == obY) || (x - 10 == obX && y == obY) || (x + 10 == obX && y + 10 == obY || (x - 10 == obX && y - 10 == obY) || (x + 10 == obX && y - 10 == obY || (x - 10 == obX && y + 10 == obY)))) {
        ctx.clearRect(x, y, 20, 20);
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        drawRect = nope;
        lose.play();
        clearInterval(moveObstacle);
        clearInterval(recreateObs);
        clearInterval(runGameOver);
        clearInterval(writeScore);
        return "Game Over";
    }
}

var runGameOver = setInterval(gameOver, 100);
```

I tried using setTimeOut() and clearTimeOut() to call and stop calling obstacle(), but nothing seemed to change. Also just calling obstacle() twice is enough for the obstacle to keep spawning again and again for some reason.

Thanks for responding. Fixed it.

Comment: `moveObstacle` will hold the id of the last `setInterval` not all of them

Comment: Glad you fixed it. It would be better to post an answer to your own question and accept it than just posting the update to the question itself.

Comment: @SmilinJasper I think what Jacob meant (and I agree) was to post it as an answer not a comment so people might find it useful in the future. The answer area is at the bottom of the page

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir lol okay, sorry. Kinda' new to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing this:

```
function obstacle() { moveObstacle = setInterval(createObstacle, 100); }
obstacle();
var recreateObs = setInterval(obstacle, 3100);

//Game Over

function gameOver() {
if ((x == obX && y - 20 == obY) || (x == obX && y + 10 == obY) || (x + 10 == obX && y == obY) || (x - 10 == obX && y == obY) || (x + 10 == obX && y + 10 == obY || (x - 10 == obX && y - 10 == obY) || (x + 10 == obX && y - 10 == obY || (x - 10 == obX && y + 10 == obY)))) {
    ctx.clearRect(x, y, 20, 20);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    drawRect = nope;
    lose.play();
    clearInterval(moveObstacle);
    clearInterval(recreateObs);
    clearInterval(runGameOver);
    clearInterval(writeScore);
    return "Game Over";
}
```

}

to this:

```
recreateObs = setInterval(function(){spawnObstacle= createObstacle, 100)}, 3100);

//Game Over
    
    function gameOver() {
        if ((x == obX && y - 20 == obY) || (x == obX && y + 10 == obY) || (x + 10 == obX && y == obY) || (x - 10 == obX && y == obY) || (x + 10 == obX && y + 10 == obY || (x - 10 == obX && y - 10 == obY) || (x + 10 == obX && y - 10 == obY || (x - 10 == obX && y + 10 == obY)))) {
            ctx.clearRect(x, y, 20, 20);
            ctx.fillStyle = "black";
            ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
            drawRect = nope;
            lose.play();
            clearInterval(recreateObs);
            clearInterval(spawnObstacle);
            clearInterval(runGameOver);
            clearInterval(writeScore);
            return "Game Over";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the moveObstacle variable outside the function and before assigning the setInterval id to it.

```js
var moveObstacleId;
function obstacle() { 
     moveObstacleId = setInterval(createObstacle, 100); 
}
obstacle();

clearInterval(moveObstacleId)
```

And do the same for other setInterval(s) functions as well.